# Question regarding notation in Goodfellow's GAN paper

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, gan

On page 3 of the [GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf) in the caption of Figure 1 there is this expression: 
$D^{*}(x) = \frac{p_{data}(x)}{p_{data}(x) + p_{g}(x)}$ 
where $p_{data}$ is the distribution of the training data and $p_{g}$ is the distribution of the generator.

What is the difference between $p_{data}(x)$ and $p_{data}$ ?

Does $D^{*}(x)$ equate to a scalar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly note, $p_{data}$ is the distribution of the training data and $p_{g}$ is the distribution of the generator. In addition, as the authors note: "*$D(x)$ represents the probability that $x$ came from the data rather than $p_g$*".

OK, let's clarify something here: $D$ is a discriminator, it is defined to be a multilayer perceptron (page 2) but it can understood more easily as being a probabilistic classifier. Thus $D$ defines a distribution and $D(x)$ defines a sample from that distribution based on the input arguments $x$. Similarly $p_{data}$ is the distribution of the training data and $p_{data}(x)$ is the probability of sample $x$ coming from $p_{data}$.

Coming to $D^*$ now, I hope it is clear that this defines another distribution (and according to authors what is an *optimal discriminator*). Therefore, $D^*(x)$ is a sample from that distribution based on the input arguments $x$. So, yes, you are correct that $D^*(x)$ can equate to a scalar (it $x$ holds a single sample) but in most cases is a vector.